# Docker container got permission error and unable to execute entrypoint script

Tags: python-3.x, django, docker

I am trying to run
docker compose build
then use the comand
docker compose up
and get this error:

```
Attaching to django-postgresql-gunicorn-nginx-dockerized-master-db-1, django-postgresql-gunicorn-nginx-dockerized-master-web-1
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown
```

Here are my Dockerfile and the entrypoint.sh

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh .

# copy project
COPY . .
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```bash
#!/bin/sh

if ["$DATABASE" = "postgres"]
then
    echo "Waiting for PostgreSQL..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
        sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

exec "$@"
```

Comment: looks like `entrypoint.sh` does not have executable flag.

Comment: do you have these files at the correct location ? and also check if the user executing the compose command has proper permission has execute access to it?

Comment: path for entrypoint.sh wrote correct,how to check it?

Comment: Your shebang is indicating sh, you could try this to see if it works, @Alex. 
`ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]`

Comment: @Toan Quoc Ho , with this code-line ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"] all working is fine,thank u for solution this problem

Comment: That's good to hear Alex, just left an answer so that other people can find the solution for the same

Comment: How are you actually running the container?  If your Compose setup has `volumes:` hiding the image's `/usr/src/app` tree then the `RUN chmod` command won't have an effect, and deleting the `volumes:` might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entrypoint that you're executing is using sh shebang. To make sure that the executor which execute your entrypoint is match so that it has enough permission to execute it.

So rather fine the right shebang for your script based on the base image: `#!/bin/bash`, ...

You can use sh for your entrypoint like so:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```